# SSH certfificates generated on server user-creation + login scheme secure?

Tags: ssh

I'm sketching on a way to harden and automate server login using ssh-keygen with certificates where certificates, valid for e.g. 1 week, are generated on a trusted server and can be used to both create the server-user and logging in. The scheme could easily be extended to support different roles, such as deployment, backup, sudo, etc.

My question is: would you say that proposed method below is secure and reliable?

In short, the steps would be:

1. User logs in to web-page
2. User provides SSH public key
3. Server generate two certificates, one for root to create the user and the other for logging in
4. User downloads the generated certificates to home-folder on client machine
5. First time accessing the server, the user would use the user-creation-certificate. Upon connection (as root), the server will create the user and then log out.
6. In normal usage, the login-certificate will be used. This certificate will need refresh once a week.
7. If a user suspects certificate loss, then the user himself or an admin can update the key revocation list from the issuing server

The most significant steps involved would be:

1. Create a user-signing key stored on a secure server. The Server could be protected by oauth2_proxy for authentication and letsencrypt for SSL. By using oauth2_proxy, the user identity becomes known and authenticated. Authorization could be by group-memberships checked by oauth2_proxy.
2. All servers be provisioned to accept users by signature of the key from step 1. (Set TrustedUserCAKeys in /etc/ssh/sshd_config) Password based login can be removed, and the key revocation list should be continuously synchronized.
3. When a user requests a create-user certificate, the user will provide his public key, and the server will create the certificate and provide to user. The identity is saved to provide key-revocation capabilities if needed.

   > ssh-keygen -s *ca-private-keyfile* -I 'create user *username* valid *NN*' -V +30d -n root -O clear -O force-command='useradd *username*' *user-provided-public-key*
4. When a user requests a login certificate, the user will provide his public key, and the server will create the certificate and provide to user. (Again, saving identity for possible key-revocation)

   > ssh-keygen -s *ca-private-keyfile* -I 'user@org valid *nn*' -V +7d -n *username* *user-provided-public-key*

Notes:

- It would be possible and recommended to add a two-factor verification step to at least the signature generation steps.
- The user should, for convenience, have two SSH key pairs to let ssh distinguish between the desired certificates.
- It would be easy to issue more types of access by changing the force-command, like getting sudo access: -n root -O force-command 'adduser *username* sudo' with the added benefit of users getting to choose when to invoke their rights and on what hosts.
- To provide more granular access, certificates can be issued with limits to host-names, or different signing key-paris can be installed on different classes of hosts.
- To provide some protection against an attacker reading the files on the issuing server (e.g. getting access to backup), the SSH key-pair could be encrypted on the server. The users who need to issue certificates would have to know the pass phrase and provide it on each signature request.

I have found a similar setup where colleagues sign each others signature requests: https://github.com/cloudtools/ssh-cert-authority but I would prefer a setup like the above.

Comment: If a "trusted server" sounds like a contradiction, an in-office no-internet machine could be used instead. Even with two-factor authentication. And a web-cam + QR code generator/reader used to import+export data. For someone not in the office, a call to a colleague to get help and share a key to e-mail encrypted public-key files would be possible.

Comment: "User logs in to web-page" - Doesn't this sort of kill the benefits of key based login?